# How to enforce each Inside method must have throw

Tags: c#

Enforce each Inside method must have throw or enforce not use try catch block.

Below example `InsideMethod2()` is not implemted `throw` in this case when it's is calling in `Main()` method, should give some warning or error message saying that you must `throw` or should not use `try` `catch` block.

Example :

```
public void Main()
{
    try
    {
        InsideMethod1();
        InsideMethod2();
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

public int InsideMethod1()
{
    try
    {
        // implementation here
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
        // log
        throw;
    }
}

public int InsideMethod2()
{
    // enforce throw or enforce not use try catch block
    int a = 1, b = 0, c = 0;
    try
    {
        c = a / b;
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
        // enforce to throw
        // log
    }

    return c;
}
```

Is it possible to enforce inside methods..?

Comment: There is none, and this is not really the worlds best idea anyway, you should be catching and throwing and logging what you need and not everything. Also it would make your log files really annoying. Basically this is why we have stack-traces

Comment: Why do you want your mtehod to throw at all? When your method can handle the error itself (e.g. the `DivideByZeroException` in `InsideMethod2`) there´s no need to provide it to the client. Instead handle it where you can (in your specific case by completyl avoiding it). This sounds pretty odd. Can you please elaborate on what you´re actual goal is. Seems like you have some completely different task to solve.

Comment: yeah sure, like i was handling with three data base which are in there different server, so updated some data in DataBase1 and DataBase2, where as while Updating in DataBase3 have some error so that time i want revert from Database1 and DataBase2 that i'll implement in Throw of Main() method.

Comment: DivideByZeroException  is just thought of example @HimBromBeere

Comment: "so that time i want revert from Database1 and DataBase2 that i'll implement in Throw of Main() method" I don´t understand that. Your db3 has any error. But why should the other two care for that? Anyway do all those databases share the same data? Otherwise it´s hard to imagine how one would "revert from a database".

Comment: You want to log every exception that occured anywhere maybe?

Comment: exactly it's one kind of sync, the same data stored over all database